# Событие на изменение значения переменной JS

Tags: javascript, node.js

Или я плохо и неправильно искал. Либо искал что-то не то.

Задача: отслеживать изменение значения переменной(в моем случае int'овый счетчик). Желательно средствами самого JS, но можно и NodeJS.

Не хотелось бы дополнительно прописывать вызовы необходимого метода в каждом месте где может меняться этот счетчик, а оставить это дело слушателю события.

Comment: На сколько я понял вам надо это [тык](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/watch) , увы работает только в лисе на сколько я понял.

Comment: @NickitaDavidenko именно оно! Не удивительно что по запросу js node event listener и похожим оно не находилось :) После .net непривычно )

Comment: @NickitaDavidenko будет ли оно работать вне браузера? Мне не нужно ничего отображать в браузере код выполняется и выводит результат в консоль терминала.

Comment: @justyx нет, не будет. Потому что node.js использует движок от Chrome - а метод watch поддерживается только в FF.

Comment: @NickitaDavidenko пожалуйста, смотрите на тэги, когда отвечаете.

Comment: @justyx кстати, про теги. Отмечать свой собственный вопрос "часто задаваемым" как-то ... неправильно. Если бы он и правда был часто задаваемым - вы бы легко нашли на него ответ.

Comment: [Это](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/observe) возможно вам подойдет.

Comment: А использовать `Proxy` не выход?

Comment: @PavelMayorov извиняюсь :) С JS буквально месяц как работаю подумал что не правильно что-то понял когда искал ответ на вопрос. Я так понимаю тег -faq добавляется модераторами уже в случае популярности вопроса?

Comment: Еще я нашел вот такой [снипет](https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583)

Comment: Просто подход изначально неверный, надо либо делать Object и делать там ф-цию типа Object.add, которая будет делать эмит и добавлять +1 в Object.int

Comment: @Other по описанию похоже что оно. Удивлен если честно что вот так заковыристо в JS с событиями :)

Comment: События в JS - это один из столпов языка, так же как замыкания, прототипы и гибкость.

Comment: @other к сожалению не сработало. При попытке повторить пример с выводом в консоль вместо алерта (мне необходимо именно это), ругнулся на 'let. 'Use strict' стоит.' "SyntaxError: Unexpected strict mode reserved word". Если же не ставить use strict то "Unexpected identifier" на user.

Comment: это отдельная переменная или поле в объекте?

Comment: @Grundy это отдельная интовая переменная "var runningProcess = 0;"